# "They saw the bus to come to the station." What is wrong with this sentence?

Tags: grammar, british-english, sentence

Please, correct (if it needs) this sentence:

> They saw the bus **to** come to the station.

Should I use *to* here?

Comment: I've closevoted as "proofreading". I think it would still be too basic for ELU even if you edit to explain exactly what aspect of the text you need help with, but at least that would make the question On Topic for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I want to know if this whole sentence grammaticaly is correct.

Comment: Obviously. But proofreading is Off Topic for both sites, so unless you edit the text to focus on some *specific* element you're unsure of, it *will* get closed. And I personally think even if you do that, the question belongs on ELL.

Comment: More CPVPV nonsense.  Nobody asks someone to "proofread" a nine-word sentence.  As Cerberus' answer notes this is a question about the suitability of a to-infinitive even if Panda-Licensed-to-Kill couldn't articulate  in thus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not correct. The verb *see* is not normally followed by *to* (just like other verbs of perception). So you can say *I saw the bus come* or *I saw the bus coming*.

Comment: Thanks. Could you say, what grammar should I know for correct using sentences like that one?

Comment: @panda007: I'm not sure I understand your question. This falls under "syntax" and verb constructions. You could Google `when should I use to infinitive, bare infinite, and gerund?`

Comment: Confusingly, *the bus was seen to come to the station* is acceptable, though (possibly) with a different shade of meaning.

Comment: The use of "was seen to come to" is still very rare, at least in the context of the original example. Even an NGram shows only four verbatim examples from 1800-2008, all of them being arguably more figurative than literal ("was seen to come to pass," "a tear was seen to come to his eye," "was seen to come to a pause"). I feel like the different shade of meaning in _the bus was seen to come to the station_ would end up being that the writer was using hypercorrective English, unintentionally or intentionally (in other words, due to ignorance or pretension).

Comment: @Rathony: Ah, I must have mislooked. Next time, feel free to correct such an error yourself.

Comment: @Rathony: I must have missed that...